# Which preposition to use after "careless?"

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

Is there a difference in meaning or usage between careless **with/about/of**?

I found dictionary examples of all three, but I failed to grasp the difference (if there is any):

> - He was careless **of** details;
> - She's rather careless **about** her appearance.
> - He's very careless **with** his money.

Thank you.

Comment: The prepositions don’t go with “careless” they go with the object that follows them.

Comment: I can see all three sentences using all three prepositions. While some versions might not be as common as others (and might even sound strange), I don't think any of them would actually be wrong. And they would all mean essentially the same thing.